Mocking a class in Python, works in namespace package, but doesn't for regular package
Context
I'm writing unit tests for my application.
I have a module in configuration/connections.py with configuration (usually defined by environment variables):
from typing import Literal

from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

class StorageConfig(BaseSettings):
    storage_name: Literal["file", "s3"]

this config is called in the module connections/storage/main.py :
import fsspec

from configuration.connections import StorageConfig

storage_config = StorageConfig()

fs: fsspec.AbstractFileSystem = fsspec.filesystem(storage_config.storage_name)

and because the environment config does not exist when I run my unit tests, I'm trying to mock the object StorageConfig:
import pytest
from pydantic import BaseModel

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def local_config(mocker):
    class LocalStorageConfig(BaseModel):
        storage_name: str = "file"

    mocker.patch("configuration.connections.StorageConfig", new=LocalStorageConfig)

Problem
Depending on my folder architecture, the mock works and sometimes does not.

If I have connections.storage as a namespace package, and my test is in connections/storage/tests/test_storage.py and that I patch directly configuration.connections.StorageConfig (as opposed to what the documentation would like me to do), it works fine.

If connections.storage is a regular package, and all the other things as in 1., it does not work anymore

If I move my test in tests/integration/test_storage.py and keep all the other things as in 2., it works.


Question

Why does regular package and namespace package have an impact on the mock?
Why is the position of my test file impacting the mock?
Why can't it work when I patch connections.storage.main.StorageConfig as the documentation suggest it would?

Thank you for your time and helping me to understand this issue :)

main.py uses the name StorageConfig (or main.StorageConfig), not configurations.connections.StorageConfig. That's the name you need to patch.
import pytest
from pydantic import BaseModel

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def local_config(mocker):
    class LocalStorageConfig(BaseModel):
        storage_name: str = "file"

    mocker.patch("connections.storage.main.StorageConfig", new=LocalStorageConfig)


it does not work. It says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'" as I was expecting.

My third question mentioned patching connections.storage.main.StorageConfig, but I said it was not working

I didn't give main its fully qualified name. The main point is that main.py uses a "local" global name, so that's what you  need to patch, not just the name that's imported.

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, patching "connections.storage.main.StorageConfig" does not work, while patching "configuration.connections.StorageConfig" works.
I'm gonna try to create a reproducible example :)
